# Microsoft Access DB issue with date filter

Tags: ms-access

I'm having issues with my DB on Microsoft Access, I use this filter to get on my form the dates from today:

```
(Year([Open Tasks].[Data])=Year(Date()) AND DatePart("d",[Open Tasks].[Data],0)=DatePart("d",Date(),0))
```

But the querying is showing the wrong dates, for example if I select that filter and today is November 4th, it will show results from August 4th, October 4th, etc...

To show results for yesterday I use

```
(Year([Open Tasks].[Data])=Year(Date()-1) AND DatePart("d",[Open Tasks].[Data],0)=DatePart("d",Date()-1,0))
```

Same issue if today is Nov 4th, it will show the results for Nov 3rd, Oct 3rd, Aug 3rd, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what "the dates from today" means. To see if a date is the same as the current date you can use `DateValue([Open Tasks].[Data])=Date()` and for yesterday `DateValue([Open Tasks].[Data])=DateAdd("d",-1,Date())`

You only need `DateValue` if your field is either text instead of date or it may contain a time element.

If for some reason you have to use this form:

```
Year([Open Tasks].[Data])=Year(Date())
```

Use

```
Year([Open Tasks].[Data])=Year(Date()) AND Month([Open Tasks].[Data])=Month(Date()) AND Day([Open Tasks].[Data])=Day(Date())
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked. The code I had used to work fine until I run the DB on a computer with a different version of Access, when I tried to run on mine, the string I put on my original post started to get messy.

The "dates from today" I meant that, everyday a lot of new entrances are added to the database, and in the of the day, to make the balance, I need to filter all the entrances from that day.

Sorry for my english, and I'm glad that your solution solved my problem,